# Inserting into an Excel VBA string

Tags: vba, excel

In JAVA or C++, we can do something along the line of `myString.insert(position, word)`. Is there a way we can do the same in Excel VBA's string? In my worksheet, I have a string looks like this: `01 / 01 / 995`, I wants to insert a 1 into the year, so make it `01 / 01 / 1995`.

```
Dim test_date As String
test_date = "01 / 25 / 995"
test_date = Mid(test_date, 1, 10) & "1" & Mid(test_date, 11, 4)
```

Is there another easier / more elegant  way to do it?

Comment: Use `Mid$` not `Mid`, the former is a string function, the later a variant function. string functions are faster

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I dont think there is a cleaner way of doing it so you could just wrap it up in a function. Another way of doing it would be with `replace`, but it's not any cleaner.

```
Function Insert(source As String, str As String, i As Integer) As String
    Insert = Replace(source, tmp, str & Right(source, Len(source)-i))
End Function
```

or just modify what you have

```
Function Insert(source As String, str As String, i As Integer) As String
    Insert = Mid(source, 1, i) & str & Mid(source, i+1, Len(source)-i)
End Function
```

Comment: Old thread, but easier/more elegant solution by (ab)using the `WorksheetFunction.Replace` that works slightly differently from VBA.Replace. I give an exemple in my answer below

Answer (score 5):

This a version of the accepted answer, with added tests and working the way I would expect it to work:

```
Function Insert(original As String, added As String, pos As Long) As String

    If pos < 1 Then pos = 1
    If Len(original) < pos Then pos = Len(original) + 1

    Insert = Mid(original, 1, pos - 1) _
                        & added _
                        & Mid(original, pos, Len(original) - pos + 1)

End Function
```

The tests pass:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print Insert("abcd", "ff", 0) = "ffabcd"
    Debug.Print Insert("abcd", "ff", 1) = "ffabcd"
    Debug.Print Insert("abcd", "ff", 2) = "affbcd"
    Debug.Print Insert("abcd", "ff", 3) = "abffcd"
    Debug.Print Insert("abcd", "ff", 4) = "abcffd"
    Debug.Print Insert("abcd", "ff", 100) = "abcdff"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my fifty cents for this question.

First of all, I need to give credit to WONG, Ming Fung from [wmfexel](https://wmfexcel.com/2017/11/25/insert-a-text-string-into-a-specific-position-of-another-text-string-in-excel/) where I found this trick.

Unlike the VBA `Replace` function who asks for the String to replace, the `Replace` Worksheet function only asks for the position in the Origin String and the number of characters to overwrite.

By "abusing" this overwrite parameter, setting it to 0 allows us to add a given string at a specific position in an Orignin string by replacing 0 characters of it.

Here it how it works :

```
Dim test_date As String
test_date = "01 / 25 / 995"
test_date = Worksheetfunction.Replace(test_date, 11, 0, "1")
'Now test_date = "01 / 25 / 1995" as we added "1" at the 11th position in it
```

As you can see, it's really convenient and readable.
For those who are picky and thinks the name Replace is just confusing, Wrap it in an Insert function and you'll be all done ;).

Answer (score 0):

```
          Public Function stringReplace(source As String, _
                                        sought As String, _
                                        substitute As String _
                                       ) As String
           Const THIS_PROC As String = "_stringReplace"
           Const THIS_MOD As String = "Module1" '--> mod declares
           Const isDBUG As Boolean = True 'usually in module declarations
           Dim tempa_ As Variant 'the _ is there to say: hey! I'm an array_
           Dim temps As String
           On Error Goto EH                 'local and normal
           If izDBUG Then On Error Goto DBUG 'instant gratification

            tempa_ = Split(source, sought)
            'handy spot to perform select manipulations
            temps = Join(tempa_, substitute)
EX: 
     Let stringReplace = temps
     DoEvents
     Exit Function
EH:
    Let temps = "ERROR!"
    Goto EX
DBUG:
     Debug.Print (THIS_MOD & THIS_PROC), Err.Number, Err.Description
     Debug.Assert NOT izDBUG : Resume
```

Comment: Really just two lines of interest: Split and Join. but I was/am just cutting and pasting (my own work.). I figured if I edit anything I will break it.  I can't stand finding (or putting) broken code on the Interwebs.